# Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress на другой домен(локальный сервер)?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

В настройках поменял адреса сайта но новый, бд работает. Но стили не грузятся, а логах chrome, адрес localhost как корневой, хотя подключаемые файлы стилей подгружаются при помощи функции get_template_directory_uri(). Не могу понять что нужно еще поменять?

Comment: Файл `wp-config.php` правили?

Comment: В базе данных остались ссылки на старый адресс, нужно указать новый.

Comment: Нужно смотреть параметры в файле `wp-config.php` и первые две записи в таблице `wp_options` базы данных

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress хранит в базе все ссылки как абсолютные. Если ваш текущий домен называется example.com, то все внутренние ссылки выглядят примерно так: http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/foo.jpg

Для правильной работы сайта на новом домене (скажем, test.ru) все ссылки в базе надо поменять на такие: http://test.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/foo.jpg

В целях массовой замены ссылок в базе можно использовать [Search and Replace Database](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). Если сайт остается на месте, то этого достаточно.

Для переноса сайта на другой сервер удобнее использовать плагин [Duplicator](https://tah.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/).

Comment: Добавлю еще команду `search-replace` у консольной wp-cli: https://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/
Переношу с её помощью.

Comment: открываешь базу ищешь examle.com выделяешь Ctrl+H быстрая замена и меняешь на test.com и все готово и не нужно нечего, и не нужны плагины можно все ручками ручками сделать, если они из правильного места поросли

Comment: @LieutenantJimDangle такая процедура возможна только в том случае, если база уже импортирована на локальный компьютер.

А главное, совершенно не работает, если ссылки находятся в сериализованных данных тем, плагинов, слайдеров и т.п. 100% гарантия, что угробите базу.

Так что ручками можно поправить базы только самых примитивных сайтов на WordPress.

Для всех прочих - вышеуказанные плагины, которые правильно работают с сериализованными данными.

Comment: @KAGGDesign ты издеваешь? если сайт не на вп и некоторые базы через миграцию подключаются то каким методом ты это будешь делать, и что значит угробишь базу? если переносишь на другой домен, то полюбому нужно менять все урлы и как раз выделив конкретно foo.com то легко можно заменить на bar.com

Comment: @LieutenantJimDangle вот пример сериализованной строки с описанием товара WooCommerce (несущественное убрал в многоточие ...)
(107, 'a:5:{ ... s:48:"http://elitechs.ru/?post_type=product&#038;p=101";s:10:"menu_order"; ...),

замена elitechs.ru здесь на test.ru угробит базу.

Понятно, почему?

Comment: @KAGGDesign sql запросы не судьба?

Comment: Ctrl+H в sql запросах?